# How to prevent global objects being compiled out in a free-standing environment

Tags: operating-system, x86, g++, assembly

I'm creating global objects in different compilation units which are constructed in a self-made startup-code:

```
.startup:
    mov ebx, start_ctors
    jmp .ctor_loop
.call_ctor:
    call [ebx]
    add  ebx, 4 
.ctor_loop:
    cmp  ebx, end_ctors
    jb   .call_ctor

    call main
```

I need to do so in order to execute my application in a free-standing environment. However, I'm using `i586-elf-g++` (4.6.0) with the following command-line options:

```
-march=i386 -masm=att -std=c++0x -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -O1
```

My linker-script looks like that:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x8000;

    .text ALIGN(0x1000) : { *(.text) }

    .rodata ALIGN(0x1000) :
    {
        start_ctors = .;
        *(.ctor*)
        end_ctors = .;

        start_dtors = .;
        *(.dtor*)
        end_dtors = .;

        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .data ALIGN(0x1000) : { *(.data) }
    .bss  ALIGN(0x1000) : { *(.bss)  }
}
```

`g++` doesn't include every constructor into the constructor-list. If I remove any optimization (by using the command-line option `-O0`) then everything works fine ...

Comment: Do the omitted constructors do anything non-trivial?

Comment: You told the compiler to omit the global constructors, and it did so, so what?

Comment: @ninjalj - Yes, they initialize their member variables.

Comment: @drhirsch - I told the compiler to omit the call of consturctors for global or static objects. That doesn't mean he should remove the constructor functions themselves.